# Dependecy Injection not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly-10

my qualifier is :

```
@Qualifier
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface JPADAOQ {
}
```

this is the bean that i want inject

```
@JPADAOQ
@ApplicationScoped
public class PlotDaoImpl extends JpaDao<Long, Plot> implements PlotDao {
    public PlotDaoImpl() {
      super(Plot.class);
    }
}
```

finally here is where i want my bean to be injected

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PlotController {
    @Inject @JPADAOQ
    private PlotDaoImpl plotDaoImpl;

    @PostConstruct  
    public void init() {        
      if (plotDaoImpl==null) {
        System.out.println("plotDaoImpl null");
      } else {
        System.out.println("plotDaoImpl not null"); 
      }
    }
```

But i always got it null so i can't use it.

My configuration : 
**1.beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

**2.pom.xml**
based on wildfly quickstart form [here](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/cdi-injection).

```
   <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I can't figure out why my bean is not injected int @PostConstruct method.

Answer (score 2):

`@javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped` specify that the JSF managed bean is application scoped, yet you must annotated to be a managed bean.

`@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped` is a CDI story. You must produce it somehow. Maybe add a method in PlotDaoImpl annotated with @Produces that returns `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I assume your `@ApplicationScoped` is in fact `javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped`. Although it would cause no harm if it wasn't as `all` discovery mode will still pick the class as a bean.

Secondly, `@ManagedBean` annotation can be removed as the CDI will automatically pick up the class as a [managed bean](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#_managed_beans).

And thirdly, make sure you actually have an active session when you test your `PlotController`. You have to let CDI create the `PlotController` bean for you in order to make injection work.

If naught else helps, you might try to replace `@SessionScoped` with `@RequestScoped` as the behaviour might slightly differ when it comes to bean availability [during `@PostConstruct` methods](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#_built_in_scopes) but that is just a guess.